# TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple) datetime Python

Tags: python, date, datetime, timedelta

I am trying to get the days between two dates. Here is my code:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
def days_diff(a, b):
    f = date(a)
    s = date(b)
    return abs(f-s)
print(days_diff((2014, 8, 27), (2014, 1, 1)))
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)
```

I wonder why? I imported the date and timedelta. Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `date(*a)`!

Comment: _I wonder why?_ Did you read the error message? What is there to speculate about? _I imported the date and timedelta._ Is that related to the issue? Also, please provide the entire error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You faced error because you passed a tuple to the `date()`, which takes values but not a tuple.
Try this:

```
def days_diff(a, b):
    f = date(*a)
    s = date(*b)
    print(f,s)
    return abs(f-s)
```

Now call it:

```
print(days_diff((2014, 8, 27), (2014, 1, 1)))
```

This will give you:

```
2014-08-27 2014-01-01
238 days, 0:00:00
```

---

The `*` takes out the value of the tuple passed (unpack the tuple).

---

To get the days alone, use `.days` :

```
return print(abs(f-s).days)
```

Comment: How can I get the output without 0:00:00?

Comment: @Rashida That's another question entirely, I'm sure you can find an answer to that elsewhere on SO.

Comment: @Rashida i've the answer to remove the 0:00:00

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass 3 parameters to `date()`, not a `tuple`. You can unpack the tuples in your function with:

```py
f = date(*a)
s = date(*b)
```